# Different value of derivative after applying Leibniz Rule

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was trying to find the general differential question of $\arcsin(x)$ for Taylor's series and noticed this:

$$y=\arcsin^2(x)\\y_1=2(\arcsin(x))\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Squaring both sides
$$y_1^2=4y\left(\dfrac1{1-x^2}\right)\\y_1^2(1-x^2)=4y$$
Taking derivative wrt $x$
$$2y_1y_2(1-x^2)+y_1^2(-2x)-4y_1=0$$ $$(1-x^2)y_2-xy_1-2=0\tag1\label{eq1}$$
Taking $n$th derivative by applying [Leibniz Rule:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)
$$y_{n+2}(1-x^2)-2nxy_{n+1}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}(-2)y_n-y_{n+1}x-ny_n=0\\y_{n+2}(1-x^2)-(2n+1)xy_{n+1}-n^2y_n=0$$
when $x=0$,
$$y_{n+2}=n^2y_n\tag2\label{eq2}$$

So when I calculate $y_2$ by $\eqref{eq1}$, I get $y_2=2$
But when I do the same by $\eqref{eq2}$, $$y_2=(0)^2y_0=0$$ I get $y_2=0$

Why this inconsistency?
I know I am making a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: To get $(1)$, you divided by $y_1$. This assumed that $y_1$ is not zero. So you cannot use $(1)$ for the values of $x$ that give $y_1=0$ (one of which is $x=0$)

Comment: Where did $y_2$ come from ???

Comment: I see that (1) is OK. Maybe it helps when you define $f$ and $g$ properly before applying  the Leibniz rule.